# Saving data after read

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to save data after the same model read it. Here's my code:

```
public function partner($postid, $partner){
    $this->Partner->id = $postid;
    $this->Partner->id = $partner;
    $this->Partner->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $result = $this->Partner->read();
    if($result){
        $time = $result['Partner']['time'];
        pr($result);
    }



    $data = array('id' => $partner,
                  'post' => $postid,
                  'time' => time(),
                  'cash' => '0.001',
                  'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $this->Partner->save($data);
}
```

It just updates the data, but doesn't save it as a new row

Comment: Can you post what the save() function does?

Comment: may be you are passing wrong data to array field id, may be it should be  $postid.

Comment: These two lines are confusing: `$this->Partner->id = $postid; $this->Partner->id = $partner;`. Why are You doing this? I don't think that passing `$partner` to a `$data['id']` variable is correct...

Answer (score 0):

Before `$this->Partner->save($data);`, call `$this->Parter->create();`, that will set the `Partner` model to save a new row.

EDIT: Unless `id` is your model's primary key and you're setting it to a value that already exists in the database, in that case it will update regardless of whether you use `$model->create()` or not. (I think).

Comment: To clarify, you can update a few different ways: setting `Model->id` which `Model->create()` will reset, or passing the PK field in the save data which `Model->create()` will *not* reset. Regardless, he's passing the id in the data so it's always going to update...

Comment: Indeed, assuming `id` is the primary key of course (which is pretty likely).